# Can i create another div from existing div on button(Add) click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<div id="div1">
    @Html.LabelFor(i=>i.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i=>i.FirstName)<br>

    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.LastName)<br>

    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Age)<br>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i =>i.Age)

    <br><input type="submit" onsubmit="submit" id="btn1" value="submit">
    <input type="button" value="add" id="btn2">
    <input type="button" value="sub" id="btn3">

</div>
```

Comment: yes but but what is the code you have posted?

Comment: Use the jquery `.clone()` method

Comment: please add some more explanation to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example

*html:*

```
<div id="content">
    <div>div content</div>
</div>
```

*javascript:*

```
$(function()  {
    $('#copy').click(function(){
        var content = $('#content div').clone();
        $('#content').after(content);
    });
  });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avdgkkkv/)